# Probability of no 2 heads occurring succesively?

Tags: probability

I'm trying to do exercise 1.53 in the Probability: An Introduction (Grimmett). Here is the problem:

> A biased coin shows heads with probability $p = 1 − q$ whenever it is
> tossed. Let $u_n$ be the probability that, in $n$ tosses, no two heads
> occur successively. Show that, for $n ≥ 1, u_{n+2} = qu_{n+1} + pqu_{n}$

I'm attempting to prove by induction, but I'm not sure if it's the right approach. I've proved that $u_{3}=qu_{2}+pqu_{1}$.

$pqu_{1}=p+q$

$pqu_{2}=2pq$

$pqu_{3}=q^3+3pq^2+p^2q=qu_{2} + pqu_{1}$

However, I'm not sure how to complete the proof by induction. I've tried:

Assume $u_{n+2} = qu_{n+1} + pqu_{n}$

Then $u_{n+3} = qu_{n+2} + pqu_{n+1}$

Then I tried to substitute $qu_{n+1} + pqu_{n}$ for the $u_{n+2}$ term in the second equation, which resulted in
$u_{n+3} = q(qu_{n+1} + pqu_{n}) + pqu_{n+1}$

I'm not sure where to go from here. Is induction even the way to prove this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to identify the recursive relation here.

Consider two cases:

1. First toss is heads, then next toss must be tails; and no constraints on next toss
2. First toss is tails, then there is no constraint on next toss

Using this knowledge, can you simplify $u_{n+2}$ in terms of $u_n$ and $u_{n+1}$?